# $(document).on('click', '[button-id]', function() {}) not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask why these lines of code doesn't work. I would like to show a table of records from my database with the aid of a button. I already called the jquery library    ..I'm pretty new to jquery though. I hope you could help me out with this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function fetch_month1() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "month1.php";
      method: "POST";
      success: function(data) {
        $('#link-con').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
  $(document).on('click', '#btn-month1', function() {
    fetch_month1();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-bar" name="top-bar">
  <button type="button" id="btn-month1" class="btn-month">Month 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a console log inside ajax.success to see if there's any errors in PHP. Or console log inside ferth_month1 to see if funct is called.

Comment: is the click event working? put a console.log when the button is clicked

Comment: That code has syntax issues; you need commas, not semi-colons, after the options in your ajax call. Use an editor that shows issues in real-time, or check the browser console for errors.

Comment: checking the snippet will `show/tell` you the problem

Comment: Ajax options must split by commas not semi-colons!

Comment: Thanks for the help...I'm having trouble in checking my jquery codes thanks for the console.log tip and pointing out the syntax error of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done minor mistake , you have used $(document).on('click') inside $(document).ready()

inside `$(document).ready()` you have to call function like this `$('#id').click(function(){ ... });`

if you want to use `$(document).on('click','#id',function(){ .... });` then define this outside of `$(document).ready()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            function fetch_month1()
            {
               alert('fetch_month1 called');
                /*$.ajax({
                    url:"month1.php";
                    method:"POST";
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('#link-con').html(data);
                    }
                });*/
            }

            $('#btn-month1').click(function(){
                    fetch_month1();
            });
});



$(document).on('click','#btn-month2',function(){
      fetch_month2();
});

function fetch_month2(){
  alert('fetch_month2 called');
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  

<div id="top-bar" name="top-bar">
    <button type="button" id="btn-month1" class="btn-month">Month 1</button>  
 <button type="button" id="btn-month2" class="btn-month">Month 2</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: this answer does not answer why OP code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like below,

```
script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {    
                $('#btn-month1').click(function () {

                    fetch_month1();

                  });
        });

 function fetch_month1()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"month1.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('#link-con').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: His function error because ajax options must split by commas not semi-colons, not error because `$(document).on('click', '#btn-month1', function() {`

Comment: @MinhNguyen this is a correct answer it only lacks explanation, plus the OP should be closed as the error is a bit obvious